# Mobile Sim Internet Speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, speed

Hi I want to ask someone here about network speed test. I am from Thailand. I got a gift data package of 12 GB at 100mbps from my mobile sim operator.

When I make a network speed test, it says the max speed is around 50 mbps. So does it mean it is the max network speed available in my area? If I buy a data package which is unlimited but announced at 30 mpbs without speed reduction, then will it perform at most 30 mbps since it is still less than the max available speed of 50 mbps?

Please someone explain me about this.

[image: speed shot]

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. This specific site is not about mobile telephone or mobile connection, but if the question is related to the use of computer it could be on topic. My suggestion is to [edit] your question, adding the information that you want to use this gift data package, for example with a laptop tethering or using the sim inside a modem and you will probably avoid some close prompts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I make a network speed test, it says the max speed is around 50 mbps. So does it mean it is the max network speed available in my area?

It says that's the max network speed available in your area, at the current time, with your specific modem, and with the current signal conditions.

A different modem (e.g. different LTE 'CAT'egory) *may* be able to reach higher speeds. Performing the same test at 4am when everyone's asleep *may* be able to reach higher speeds compared to when the cell tower is being heavily used.

> If I buy a data package which is unlimited but announced at 30 mpbs without speed reduction, then will it perform at most 30 mbps since it is still less than the max available speed of 50 mbps? Or will the speed be reduced proportionally i.e. max at 50 mbps for 100 mpbs announced speed and thus 15 mbps for 30 mbps?

If you get a "30 Mbps" plan, then the ISP will simply limit your traffic to 30 Mbps maximum. It's a hard limit, not a proportional limit, because it is done elsewhere in the ISP's infrastructure and doesn't depend on the modem or cell tower's capabilities.